# how to create a list of values based on a index python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list

input :
value = [1,2,2,1,1,3,1,3,4,4,5,5,4,6,6]

expected output:

[[1,2,3,1,1,3,1],[3],[4,4,5,5,4],[6,6]]

Explanation:

1) once i iterate over value list first element would we 1 index's of one are 
[0 3 4 6] . i want to store start and end number of a index eg (value[ 0  : 6 ]) to a new list and remove from Existing one list looks like value= [3,4,4,5,5,4,6,6]

2) once i iterate on value next input would be 3  index of value 3 is [0] store it in a list and as follows

I have tried few lines of code

1) i have iterated a list with index and value with numpy i have found the index stored in a table

```
import numpy as np
final_list=[]
top_list=[1,2,2,1,1,3,1,3,4,4,5,5,4,6,6]

matched_input=[]
for i,j in enumerate(top_list):
    if(len(matched_input)==0):
        values = np.array(top_list)
        matched_input= np.where(j == values)[0]
        matched_input=np.array(matched_input).tolist()
        final_list.append(top_list[matched_input[0]:matched_input[-1]+1])
        #print matched_input
    elif(len(matched_input)>0 and i not in range(matched_input[-1]+1)):
        values= np.array(top_list[matched_input[-1]+1:])
        matched_input_updated= np.where(j == values)[0]
        matched_input_updated=np.array(matched_input_updated).tolist()
        final_list.append(top_list[matched_input_updated[0]:matched_input_updated[-1]+1])
```

Comment: `[0 3 4 6] i want to store those list to a new list`... Don't understand... What does that have to do with the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```py
input = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 6, 6]

result = []
while len(input) > 0:  # can be just while input
    first_element = input[0]
    last_index_of_first_element = len(input) - (input[::-1].index(first_element) + 1)
    result.append(input[:last_index_of_first_element + 1])
    input = input[last_index_of_first_element + 1:]

print(result)
```

Output:

> [[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1], [3], [4, 4, 5, 5, 4], [6, 6]]

basically, as long as there is input, I take the first element, then find it's last index (by reversing the list, finding the first index, and subtracting from the len), and then use slicing to extract the correct sublist and append to result.

Answer (score 2):

Slight variation on [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56752226/1782792), without modifying the input list:

```
value = [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 6, 6]
next_idx = 0
value_rev = value[::-1]
result = []
while next_idx < len(value):
    prev_idx = next_idx
    next_idx = len(value) - value_rev.index(value[prev_idx])
    result.append(value[prev_idx:next_idx])
print(result)
# [[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1], [3], [4, 4, 5, 5, 4], [6, 6]]
```

Comment: +1 for preserving original input, additionally I love how concise the body of the loop is, without all the +1 index corrections.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

value = [1,2,2,1,1,3,1,3,4,4,5,5,4,6,6]
d = defaultdict(list)
[d[v].append(i) for i, v in enumerate(value)]

i, out = 0, []
while i < len(value):
    i2 = d[value[i]][-1]
    out.append(value[i:i2+1])
    i = i2 + 1

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1], [3], [4, 4, 5, 5, 4], [6, 6]]
```